# Regular Expression validation on Google Forms to block Words

Tags: regex, google-forms

I'm trying to use Regular Expression Validation on Google Forms to block some specific words (bad words), in any sequence of uppercase/lowercase. ex[with other types of words]:
to block -> **wood, Wood, WoOd...** and **river, River, RiVeR...** and so on. I'm using -> `([Ww][oO][Oo][Dd]|[Rr][Ii][Vv][Ee][Rr])` (i made a python script do "duplicate" each letter and create the expression, so it's easiest not to use `x{0,y}`, and at least for now, there is no dupli letters on my words list)

It is working good. And as looks that `(?i:wood)|(?i:river)` or `(?i)wood|(?i)river` don't works there, as i know, it is the better way i can do it.

The main problem is that one specific word of the list is also a kind of commom last name here in Brazil, lets say..."Manequim", and i still want to block this word, except when it is typed ONLY with the first letter in UpperCase.
So i need to block "manequim" by all the ways: "manequim", "MANEQUIM", "MaNeQuIm", etc, except by the formal way of Names/Last Names: "Manequim", but i'm not getting a good way to do that

Would somebody have a solution??

Thanks for the help and sorry by the probably confuse english

Comment: What specifically does the regex need to do? Group the offending word? Make a match when there's at least 1 offensive word? Match only when there are no offensive words?

Comment: The item is set like this: http://imgur.com/PukebyH

If ANY regex becomes true (it meas that its offensive word has found), the form show an erros message and don't allow to submit it: http://imgur.com/56HG2bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`(?!Manequim)[Mm][Aa][Nn][Ee][Qq][Uu][Ii][Mm]`](https://regex101.com/r/CJIMPT/1)

- `(?!Manequim)` Check to make sure the following text is *not* the "okay" version.
- `[Mm][Aa][Nn][Ee][Qq][Uu][Ii][Mm]` Check the following word to see if it makes up the "bad" version. If this text would make the "okay" version it wouldn't even get this far.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. But it didn't work on Google Forms